# Plot a histogram together with an UpSet plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetr, upsetplot

I have a data frame that looks like this,

```
  df <- data.frame(type=c("SNP","DEL","SNP","SNP"),geneA=c(1,1,1,0), geneB=c(0,0,1,1), geneC=c(1,0,0,1))

   type geneA geneB geneC
1  SNP     1     0     1
2  DEL     1     0     0
3  SNP     1     1     0
4  SNP     0     1     1
```

I want to make an UpSet plot in R to find the common genes and
I want to plot the distribution of types (SNP or DEL) in an histogram.

this is my code so far

```
  upset(df, 
        attribute.plots = list(gridrows=50,
                           plots=list(list(plot=histogram,
                                           x="type"))))
```

and this is my error, which I can not solve

```
Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete.Perhaps you want stat="count"?
```

[image]

**ANY help is highly appreciated**

Comment: If you want to combine ggplot2 components with upset I can suggest an alternative I created for that purpose: https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset.

Comment: Its a bit complicate to me how it works. If I try something like this
```upset(df, 
      annotations = list(
        'type'=(
          ggplot(mapping=aes(fill=type))
          + geom_bar(stat='count', position='fill'))))
```
I am still getting an error. Maybe because its late at night in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what `the distribution of types (SNP or DEL) in an histogram` means exactly. However, because the data of SNP and DEL in your example are binaries, you probably want to plot the counts of SNP and DEL in a bar plot. If that's true, you can try this way:

```
mybarplot <- function(mydata, x) {
  (ggplot(mydata, aes_string(x = x)) + geom_bar()
  + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0), "cm"), 
          legend.key.size = unit(0.4, "cm")))
}
```

This function takes a data frame and one of its column as its inputs, and
generates a barplot as its output. Then, you call this function within your `upset` function to produce the barplot along with your upset plot.

```
upset(dftest, attribute.plots = list(gridrows = 50, 
                                     plots = list(list(plot = mybarplot, 
                                                       x = "type"))))
```

[image: the resulted plots]